# htaccess rule - relative files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It's probably an easy thing to fix however I tried to google this stuff but I'm not sure how to put it in words so I couldn't find anything which would help me.

I have a problem where my very simple .htaccess changes my url as it supposed to but all the resources are trying to get loaded from a wrong place.

My Url:

```
http://domain.com/index.html?sport=test
```

My re-written Url:

```
http://domain.com/test/
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.html?sport=$1 [L]
```

now when I type in: `http://domain.com/test/` it loads the correct index file however every resource file is trying to get downloaded from test folder...

this is an example resource file location (relative to the index.html):

```
css/styles.css
js/main.js
```

but it's looking for them in:

```
test/css/styles.css
test/js/main.js
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit the most common problem people face when switching to pretty URL schemes. Solution is also simple, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

OR you can try adding this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Also, `http://domain.com` should not trigger the rewrite, leaving you looking for `/index.*` -- is that OK? How about `http://domain.com/`? I suspect it will give you `/index.html?sport=` which will probably be in error. (Aside: is it really index.html receiving a Query String?) `http://domain.com/test` isn't going to match, either, as you didn't make the trailing / optional (`/?`).